# Multiple Add-ins with the same custom ribbon group

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I want to target the same custom group in the ribbon as another one of my add-ins but Word just keeps creating new groups with the same name.

Here is what I have

#### Manifest 1

```
...
<Group id="MyCustomGroup">
    <Label resid="MyCustomGroupLabel" />
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyCustomButton1">...</Control>
</Group>
...
```

#### Manifest 2

```
...
<Group id="MyCustomGroup">
    <Label resid="MyCustomGroupLabel" />
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyCustomButton2">...</Control>
</Group>
...
```

I would expect to see the buttons in the same group, but instead it creates 2 groups with one icon in each.

I understand that there is a restriction on adding buttons to built-in groups, but I can't seem to work out how to do it for custom groups.

Comment: In the COM world, you'd need to use the attribute `idQ` in order to share tabs and groups between solutions. You can look whether that's available in the Office JS model (I simply don't know). But the Office JS commands don't provide the same capabilities as "RibbonX" (the COM version), so it may simply not be possible - which wouldn't surprise me, given "Sandboxing".

Comment: Good to know, Customer asked me as well for a second plugin that should be in the same Group as the one I'm currently developping. I find MS should implement a big warning that the functionalities of javascript add-ins are super limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. With Office Web Add-ins, each custom ribbon group is linked to the unique `<ID>`, of the add-in that creates it, in the add-in's manifest. So, Office sees these as distinct groups.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? We have 5 add-ins that we want to display in one group.